# sharepoint active directory anonymous login

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, anonymous

The sharepoint which i am using uses active directory authentication. I am working on a workflow which will send a form to end user to fill up his information. The end user is not part of active directory. Is there anyway to bypass the authentication?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a bit late.....

I don't think you want to bypass the authentication. You want to know who is filling out that form.

What I have done in the past is set up both Forms Based Authentication (FBA) and Active Directory (AD) on the same site collection.  Then when the user logs in they are presented with a drop down asking them which authentication method they want to use.

Another option would be to create another SharePoint web application that is available to your external clients that uses the same content database as your internal SharePoint site that uses AD. Then configure FBA on that web app.

Here is an article that might help you get started:[stackexchange article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93647/fba-and-ad-authentication-can-work-together)